# Not receiving emails from sendgrid-Node JS

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I got my 'from' verified through sendgrid but am still not receiving any emails. There's also no error log which could help me figure out what's going wrong. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
  User.findOne({
    email: email
  })
  .then(userDoc => {
    if (userDoc) {
      req.flash('emailError', 'Email ID already exists!');
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }
    return bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
    .then(hashedPassword => {
      const user = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        cart: {
          items: [],
          totalPrice: 0
        }
      });
      return user.save();
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/login');
      return transporter.sendMail({
        to: email,
        from: 'bhowalsoham@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Signup succeeded',
        html: '<h1>You successfully signed up!</h1>'
      }); 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: You are returning from user.save(). in the first then block. And I don't get how it's working with two then()s at the same level. Please check it.

Comment: Tried your nested then block approach (with the braces added appropriately). Still, no emails.

Comment: Can you please put some logs and make sure that the sendMail() is called.

Comment: I tried console.log(transporter.sendMail === true); and it's coming out to be false.